# Git: How do I share my branch with a colleague without losing my changes?

Tags: git

I am currently working on a feature (`feature/001`). I am stuck and would like to give my branch to a colleague. My idea is to create a new branch (`feature/001-tmp`) where I copy my changes.

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout feature/001
git merge master
git stash

git checkout -b feature/001-tmp
git apply stash@{n}
git push
```

After my colleague has made his changes to the `feature/001-tmp` branch, he pushes the temporary branch back into the repository. Now I can:

```
git status
// => feature/001-tmp
git pull
git checkout feature/001
git merge feature/001-tmp
```

That was my reasoning. Can you do it that way or is there a better workflow?
Thx

Comment: Why wouldn’t you simply push `feature/001`?

Comment: @Biffen because then I can no longer recognize in my IDE which file I have edited.

Comment: I'm not adding an answer, as the existing ones are good enough, but check out [LearnGitBranching](https://learngitbranching.js.org), you'll learn how to answer any such question about git!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot lose any changes by pushing a branch. Commits are immutable and can never be changed. A branch is nothing more than a named handle for a commit. You and your colleague can still push to branches of different names.

Your command dance seems overly complicated. To push a local branch to a remote branch of a different name, use the following Git command:

```
git push origin yourlocalbranch:remotebranchname
```

e.g. `git push origin feature/001:feature/001-tmp`

Comment: I think it is a misunderstanding. Sorry. I mean the visual changes in my ide would be gone as soon as I commite my changes.

Comment: @MartinTTS I don't understand. What are "visual changes"? Pushing a branch does not change any commits, nor any local (uncommitted or unstaged) changes

Comment: I hope for you that your IDE shows your changes in your code. That is a nice feature if you work with versioning ;-). to push a branch a have to commit my changes first. After a commit the change is no longer displayed graphically.

Comment: @MartinTTS are you talking about uncommitted changes? Pushing can only push commits, if a change is not committed, it cannot be pushed. At the same time, uncommitted changes do not prevent you from pushing the existing commits (the remote would simply not contain the uncommitted changes). If you don't want to commit the changes, why do you want to push them? That sounds like a huge source for error (e.g. which changes are "definitive"?)

Comment: Yes, i  mena  uncommitted changes.. Thanks for your quick reply. It seems to me that I am making it more complicated than it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can share your branch with your colleague without losing your changes by creating a new branch and pushing it to the repository. Your colleague can then make changes to the new branch and push it back to the repository. You can then merge the changes into your original branch.

And that works, and better way to do this.
As per your scenario you can try this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So actually exactly as I described it in my question, right?